# How to use @media min-wdth and max-width to fix the width of the containers

Tags: css

I have a three sections in my webpage.
When I reduce window size, it keeps on resizing. I want to stop resizing at some point so that the contents  in the web page will not overlap.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="section1">

//code here
</div>
<div class="section2">
 // code here
</div>
<div class="section3">
 // code here.
</div>
```

Here is my css.

```
.section1{
width:14%;
}
.section2{
    width:26%;
    left:14%;
}
.section3{
    width: 60%;
    left: 40%;

}
```

I noticed at 900px width the page contents are good. I used this statement.

```
@media (min-width:900px) {
   .section1 {
      width: 5%;
    }    
    .section2{
        width: 28%;
       left: 5%;
    }
    .section3{
        width: 67%;
        left: 33%;
    }    
}
```

It is still keep on resizing to till 230 pixels but I want to stop resizing at 900 pixels. Do I have to specify the width in pixels instead of percentage?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your 3 div section into div wrapper that have a predefined hardcode width of 900px.

HTML Wrapper:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section1">

    //code here
    </div>
    <div class="section2">
     // code here
    </div>
    <div class="section3">
     // code here.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS to add:

```
.wrapper {width: 900px}
```

Hope this will help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a minimum-width the elements in question will resize only until that point.

**Example:**

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {

    .section1 {
        width: 5%;
        minimum-width: 250px;
    }

}
```

In the example above, once you hit a viewport of 900px the element will resize accordingly until it hits 250px in width, then maintain that width and stop resizing further.